# awaitMessages in DM Channel

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make an announcement bot on Discord using discord.js that when someone types -na it DM's them with an embed and then takes their input, makes a variable that is their input and then does that process a few times. The issue I'm getting is that when I run the bot and then do the command -na it gives me an error which is: TypeError: Cannot read property 'awaitMessages' of undefined.
Here is my code:

```
const allyAnnouncementChannel = client.channels.cache.get('756701256122236941')
```

```
if (msg.content === '-na') {
        if (msg.channel === Discord.DMChannel) {
            return
            } else
            if (msg.member.roles.cache.has('756713479003701338')) {
                msg.author.send(Ping);

                msg.member.dmChannel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id === msg.author.id,
                    {max: 1, time: 300000}).then(collected => {
                            msg.author.send(Title);
                            EmbedPing = collected.first().content;

                            msg.member.dmChannel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id === msg.author.id,
                                {max: 1, time: 300000}).then(collected => {
                                    msg.author.send(Message);
                                    EmbedTitle = collected.first().content;

                                    msg.member.dmChannel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id === msg.author.id,
                                        {max: 1, time: 300000}).then(collected => {
                                            msg.author.send(Image);
                                            EmbedMessage = collected.first().content;
                                            
                                            msg.member.dmChannel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id === msg.author.id,
                                                {max: 1, time: 300000}).then(collected => {
                                                    if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() === 'yes') {
                                                        msg.author.send(ImageURL);
                                                        EmbedImage = collected.first().content;

                                                        var FinishedEmbedImage = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                                            .setColor('#FFD700')
                                                            .setTitle(EmbedTitle)
                                                            .setDescription(EmbedMessage)
                                                            .setImage(EmbedImage)
                                                            .setTimestamp()
                                                            .setFooter('Sent By: ' + msg.author)

                                                        allyAnnouncementChannel.send(EmbedPing, FinishedEmbed);

                                                    } else
                                                    msg.author.send(Finished);

                                                    var FinishedEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                                        .setColor('#FFD700')
                                                        .setTitle(EmbedTitle)
                                                        .setDescription(EmbedMessage)
                                                        .setTimestamp()
                                                        .setFooter('Sent By: ' + msg.author)

                                                    allyAnnouncementChannel.send(EmbedPing, FinishedEmbed);
                                                }).catch(new Discord.MessageEmbed
                                                    .setColor('#FFD700')
                                                    .setTitle('Announcement Cancelled')
                                                    .setDescription('It has been 5 minutes without a response. The announcement has been cancelled.')
                                                    .setFooter('Please do the command again if you wish to send an announcement.'))
                                        }).catch(new Discord.MessageEmbed
                                            .setColor('#FFD700')
                                            .setTitle('Announcement Cancelled')
                                            .setDescription('It has been 5 minutes without a response. The announcement has been cancelled.')
                                            .setFooter('Please do the command again if you wish to send an announcement.'))
                                }).catch(new Discord.MessageEmbed
                                    .setColor('#FFD700')
                                    .setTitle('Announcement Cancelled')
                                    .setDescription('It has been 5 minutes without a response. The announcement has been cancelled.')
                                    .setFooter('Please do the command again if you wish to send an announcement.'))
                    }).catch(new Discord.MessageEmbed
                                .setColor('#FFD700')
                                .setTitle('Announcement Cancelled')
                                .setDescription('It has been 5 minutes without a response. The announcement has been cancelled.')
                                .setFooter('Please do the command again if you wish to send an announcement.'))
        };
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`msg.member` returns a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object. However, the [`dmChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=dmChannel) property is only available on a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User)

```js
msg.author.dmChannel.awaitMessages(...) // change `msg.member` to `msg.author`
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'awaitMessages' of null
That's the error I get when I do the command.

Comment: You have to replace `msg.member` with `msg.author`

Comment: I changed it to that and it still gave me that error.